# Visual Java App that runs on Windows and Linux

Tags: java

This is a noob question I know, but is it possible to really write a program in Java that runs on Linux and Windows? The equivalent to what is known as a Windows Form Application in the .Net world?

I don't want a "console app", but I'm after a rich front end type application that will run on Windows 7 (64bit) and Linux Ubuntu.

Is a write once solution possible?

EDIT, what I'm after is a yes (absolutely) or yes with difficulty or no, language X is more suitable, type of answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course! If you use [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/), you even get native widgets for free! :)

We have written a complete ERP that runs on Windows, Mac OS and Linux. There are some gotchas, but the parts of the app that have to be modified to be really platform independent are about 0.1%, if you do it right.

Comment: Ok, so eclipse IDE compliments the native widgets?

Comment: Yes, it does. The difference between SWT and Swing is, that SWT uses the native widgets, and Swing just draws widgets that look like they are native by itself, pixel for pixel. This is horrible slow over remote connections like RDP, so I would always recommend SWT for enterprise apps.

Answer (score 4):

As Daniel mentioned, you can use SWT but also if you just look for a tutorial on Swing this will give a good foundation on Java GUI that will work on both platforms.  There isn't really a more suitable application language that's as high level.